# CSS change image on hover of DIV doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV that change his color when mouse over

I want to change the image inside the div when mouse over the div, not over the necessarily on the image

In the HTML

```
<div class="about">
<img class="about-project1">
```

CSS

```
.about-project1 {
    width: 121px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url("img/coching.png") no-repeat;
    border: 0px;
    }

.about:hover h3 {
    color: #fff;
}

.about a about-project1:hover {
    background: url("img/coching_white.png") no-repeat;
    }
```

Another thing is that the image appears with border although i tell border:0
why ?

10x very much
Udi

Comment: Should `.about a about-project1` not be `.about about-project1`? You have no `a` tag in your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will do what you want:

**HTML**

```
<div class="about">
   <div class="about-project1"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.about-project1 {
    width: 121px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url("https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png") no-repeat;
}

.about:hover h3 {
    color: #fff;
}

.about:hover .about-project1 {
    background: url("https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

Finally, your image had a border because it was an `img` element with no `src` attribute, I changed the original code to use a `div` instead.

[Fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/ja0txnmz/12/)